# Breaking with GDB in a Node.js addon

Tags: node.js, gdb, node.js-addon

How can I break with GDB in a Node.js addon?

I have the appropriate debug information packages installed.  The addon doesn't crash, so I can't just break on a signal.  The addon is built with debugging symbols.